# epsilon delta continuous with a little spice

Tags: real-analysis

Let there be $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ which is continuous in $x_0$ and $f(x_0) \neq 0$. Show that there exists $\delta > 0$ such that

$|f(x)| \ge \frac{|f(x_0)|}{2} > 0$ for all x that $|x-x_0| < \delta$

I've tried to build on $|f(x)| \ge \frac{|f(x_0)|}{2} > 0$ but I dont even know if its the right way. Could someone show this to me?

Answer (score 2):

Notice we are given that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, let us write what this means. It means for $\mathbf{any}$ $\epsilon > 0$ we can always $\mathbf{find}$ some $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x-x_0|< \delta $, then $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon $.

We are given $f(x_0) \neq 0$, thus $|f(x_0)| > 0$. Since the above holds for any epsilon, we may $\mathbf{choose}$ $\epsilon = \frac{ |f(x_0)|}{2} > 0$. Then, we can find some $\delta > 0$ such that

$$ | f(x) - f(x_0) | < \frac{ |f(x_0)| }{2} \iff  \frac{ |f(x_0)|}{2} < f(x) < \frac{ 3 |f(x_0)| }{2}$$

whenever $|x-x_0| <\delta$

Answer (score 1):

Just to make matters a bit less abstract, let's first try out the case where $f(x_0) > 0$. That is, $\lvert f(x_0) \rvert = f(x_0)$. Using the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$-definition of continuity with $\varepsilon = f(x_0)/2$ (which is greater than 0), we obtain a $\delta > 0$ so that $\lvert f(x) - f(x_0) \rvert < f(x_0) / 2$ for all $x$ with $\lvert x - x_0 \rvert < \delta$. Rewriting this a bit, $-f(x_0) / 2 < - \lvert f(x) - f(x_0) \rvert \leq \lvert f(x) \rvert - \lvert f(x_0) \rvert$, for instance by the reverse triangle inequality. Can you take it from there?

Comment: Just do basically the same for negative?

Comment: With a tiny bit of care going into how to ensure that all relevant pieces are positive, yes.